# DNS: How to Dig thru the right domain name from the TLD?

Tags: dns, domain-name, tld, dig

I'd like to query the DNS records until get the right domain name.

For instance, given www.subdomain.site.com.br, be able to dig from .br until site.com.br.

Which is the most (protocol-speaking) way to achieve that? An recipe using dig/nslookup would be best.

Thanks.

Comment: I ended up looking for the leftmost SOA record match (i.e., from www.subdomain.site.com.br until it finds the SOA for site.com.br).

Comment: Calling that "the right domain name" is very... wrong. All domain names are right. What are you really after? When we changed the management of the zone files in ".fr", martin.nom.fr was in the zone nom.fr, now, it is in the zone fr. Did "the right domain" changed?

Comment: @bortzmeyer, you're right. However, I want to, say, given a hostname, like www.stackoverflow.com, get just stackoverflow.com, keeping the tld and any n-ary-lds but removing any element which does not belong to the zone in itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dig www.mysite.domain.com @a.root-servers.net
```

you'll get the next level from there.  Just replace the portion after the '@' and keep recursing until you query a server that gives an answer rather than additional information

Comment: Your answer gave-me the clue I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```
dig +trace www.subdomain.site.com.br
```

will show you exactly what happens.

Comment: This just times out for me (using a real domain name).  Does this depend on your machine's DNS server being configured a certain way?  Or does dig do all the work itself?

Comment: dig should do all the work itself, there's no special configuration required for the DNS server.